# Curious about curious badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-progress

My curious badge has 7/5 questions, but says I do not have a positive question record. I looked at my questions and I only have 1 question with a -1 vote, and the rest are 0 or positive.

Does the badge include deleted questions?

Or am I missing something else?

EDIT : Sorry I have a -1 and a -6 question